# Why my Google Chrome extension won't show up my popup

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

Can you provide me some help?

I've created my first chrome extension, and I wish I could make a pop up to appear.
But it doesn't work

manifest.json:

```
{
"name" :"CHROMICHROME",
"version" : "1.0.0",
"manifest_version" : 2,
"description" :"Testitest",
"browser_action" :
    {
        "default_icon" : "icon.png",
        "popup" :"bonjour.html"
    }
}
```

bonjour.html

```
<script>
alert("Bonjour!") ;
</script>
```

The extension can be loaded on chrome, but when I click on its icon nothing happen! ..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [manifest version 2](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_migration_to_manifest_v2.html), you cannot use  tags directly. You have to instead use  to load a script file, for security reasons. Example:

bonjour.html

```
<script src="bonjour.js"></script>
```

bonjour.js

```
alert("Bonjour!");
```

though I see no reason why you'd want to do an alert in a browser action ;)

Answer (score 0):

try using `"default_popup" :"bonjour.html"`